# Efficient modification of the rows of a sparse matrix in Java

Tags: java, matrix, sparse-matrix, performance, memory-efficient

I need to "normalize" a large sparse matrix so that the sum of the entries in each row is 1.  For rows that have some non-zero entries, each entry is divided by the row sum.  For rows that are all zeros, each entry is replaced by 1/numberOfColumns (making the matrix considerably less sparse).

If it matters, my matrix is square, and symmetric.  I'm working first with a "small" test sample, where my matrix is about 32K x 32K in size -- but we ultimately need this to work with much larger matrices.  Both time and memory efficiency will be important (with memory a bit more critical than time).  Before normalization about 1% of the entries are non-zero.

After normalizing the n x n matrix, it needs to be multiplied by a series of n x k dense matrices, where k is a small number (<10)

I'm currently using the la4j matrix package, but I'm not in any way tied to it.

I've included my normalization code below.  It's horribly slow, in my 32K x 32K test case.  I know from a bit of experimentation that the piece that takes the most time is re-setting the rows of the T matrix (my t.setRow lines below).

Three questions:

1) Is there a better package or better approach to doing this efficiently?

2) Should I not be using a sparse matrix representation for this?

3) Would it be best to not replace the zero rows but just keep track of which rows were zeros, and then hack the matrix multiplication accordingly?

Thanks in advance!

```
SparseMatrix t = new CRSMatrix(n, n);

// in between non-zero entries in t are added one at a time


double uniformWeight = (double) 1 / n; // used when the rowSum is zero
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Vector row = t.getRow(i);
        double rowSum = row.sum();
        if (rowSum > 0) {
            row = row.divide(rowSum);
            t.setRow(i,row);
        } else {
            row.assign(uniformWeight); // Assigns all elements of this vector to given value
            t.setRow(i, row);
        }
    }
```

**Update 1**

Here's what I tried that did speed things up quite a bit.  I haven't tried Vladimir's suggestions yet but I will add those when I get back to this project next week.  Now I am keeping a boolean array of which rows are zero rows, and should be treated as uniform rows during the matrix multipication, which is now done with my hackMultiply method.  I would appreciate Vladimir's (or others') additional advice on avoiding the `getRow` and `setRow` in that method.  Note that m2 (the second multiplicand) and m3 (the result matrix) are not sparse, if that matters.  Thanks in advance!

```
    boolean[] zeroRows = new boolean[n]; // all values default to false
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Vector row = t.getRow(i);  // haven't had a chance to try Vladimir's 
        double rowSum = row.sum(); // improvements here yet
        if (rowSum > 0) {
            row = row.divide(rowSum);  // or here
            t.setRow(i,row);           // ...
        } else {
            // instead of setting to uniform weight, just keep track
            zeroRows[i] = true;
        }
    }

/**
 * Multiplies the given matrices m1 (Sparse) and m2, with the following modifications
 * For every row in m1 for which the corrresponding entry in zeroRows is true
 * use uniformVector instead of the actual contents of the row for the multiplication
 * (Meant for the case when the replaced rows are all zeros, and we don't want 
 * to actually replace them in the SparseMatrix because then it wouldn't be sparse 
 * anymore.)
 * 
 * @param m1 First multiplicand
 * @param m2 Second multiplicand
 * @param zeroRows boolean array indicating which rows of m1 should be logically replaced by uniformVector
 * @param uniformVector vector to replace all the zeroRows with during the multiplication
 * @return the result of the hacked multiplication
 */
public static Matrix hackMultiply(SparseMatrix m1, Matrix m2, boolean[] zeroRows, Vector uniformVector) {
// for "efficiency" I'm assuming I get passed in things of appropriate sizes, no checking
    int a = m1.rows();
    int b = m2.columns();
    int c = m1.columns(); // must == m2.rows() for the matrix multiplication to work
    Matrix m3 = new Basic2DMatrix(a,b);
    Vector v1;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        if (zeroRows[i]) {
            v1 = uniformVector;
        } else {
            v1 = m1.getRow(i);
        }
        m3.setRow(i, v1.multiply(m2));
    }
    return m3;
}
```

**Update 2**

I really appreciate all the help from @Vladimir and @mikera.  For what it's worth, the version using `la4j` with the `hackMultiply` approach is pretty much identical in time use to the version using `vectorz` version 0.26.0.  It looks like the upgrades in 0.27.0 will give it a slight edge, but I haven't tried it yet.  For memory use, the la4j version with the hack is considerably better than the vectorz version, at least the way I have the code written right now.  I suspect the 0.27.0 release may help there as well.

Comment: If most of your entries are ending up non-sparse then you would almost certainly be better off using a non-sparse matrix. I would expect it to be considerably faster although I've never actually used either so I can't say so for sure.

Comment: Considering you already have over a billion cells and are going to need "much larger" data sets you are going to want some specialist libraries. You might even want to consider using graphics cards for the processing if you are doing a lot of math over the data sets as they can process it in a massively parallel way (although the size of the data sets you are talking about might be an issue there still).

Comment: @TimB thanks for your replies.  I am wondering if for memory-efficiency reasons, we would be better off trying option #3 and keeping the sparse matrix, but also tracking the zero rows, so that when doing the multiplication, we can sub in the constant uniform vector.  Thoughts?

Comment: re: "specialist libraries" -- I thought that was what la4j and similar packages were?

Comment: I'd replace each zero-row with the same pre-built row containing the same object n times. This should save you a truckload of space. Do make sure your entries and rows are immutable. i.e. instead of `row.assign(uniformWeight);row.setRow(i,row);` use `row.setRow(uniformRow)` where `uniformRow` is pre-built depending on `n`.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I agree that it's a good optimization, and may save a bit of time, but I don't see how it saves memory.  I already have the row that I pulled out of the matrix, and I'm changing it to whatever I want to put back in (and at the end of the loop iteration, row should get released for garbage collection, I believe).  How can I make sure my entries and rows are immutable?  (By the way, I think you mean `t.setRow` not `row.setRow` in your examples.)

Comment: @PurpleVermont - You are correct - should have been `row.setRow` :( The essence of my point was to suggest that *all** rows containing all-zeros are replaced by a single pre-built row containing the same object repeated n-times. This way you will save n objects for every all-zero row. Note that you should replace the **whole row**, not just all the entries.

Comment: @OldCurmudgeon I get what you're suggesting, but I'm still not clear how that saves objects.  Or at least, I don't think the `la4j` algorithms work in the way they would have to for this to work.  I think it copies the values into the matrix instead of just pointing to the vector when `setRow` is called.  (Because if I call `t.setRow(i, myFavoriteVector)` and then change some of the elements in `myFavoriteVector`, nothing changes in row `i` of `t`, so it must be copying the values and not just pointing to the vector.)

Comment: Obviously, just computing the uniformVector once will save me having to do the `assign` thousands of times, so it should save me some time anyhow, if not space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not tied to la4j, the [Vectorz](https://github.com/mikera/vectorz) package (which I maintain) has some tools to do these kinds of operations very efficiently. This is possible because of two features:

- Sparse storage of data
- Lightweight mutable "views", so you can mutate rows of a matrix as vectors in-place

The strategy I would use is:

- Create a `VectorMatrixMN` to store a matrix as a collection of sparse vector rows
- Use a `SparseIndexedVector` for each row, which is an efficient format for mostly-zero data

Normalising the rows of the matrix can then be done with the following code:

```
VectorMatrixMN m = ....

for (int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
    AVector row=m.getRow(i);
    double sum=row.elementSum();
    if (sum>0) {
        row.divide(sum);
    } else {
        m.setRow(i, new RepeatedElementVector(SIZE,1.0/SIZE));
    }
}
```

Note that this code is modifying the rows in-place, so you don't need to do anything like "setRow" to get the data back in the matrix.

Using this configuration with a 32,000 x 32,000 sparse matrix and a density of 100 non-zero values per row, I timed this at less than 32ms to normalise the whole matrix with this code (i.e. about 10ns per non-zero element == 0.03ns per matrix element : so you are clearly getting big benefits by exploiting the sparsity).

You could also optionally use a `ZeroVector` for rows that are all-zero (these will be even faster, but impose some extra constraints since ZeroVectors are immutable.....)

**EDIT:**

I've coded a complete example that demonstrates using sparse matrices for a use case very similar to this question:

- https://github.com/mikera/vectorz/blob/develop/src/test/java/example/SparseMatrix.java

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @mikera.  In our original matrix, I believe that in most cases, most of the rows will be all-zeros, which means that after we do the normalization, it will no longer be sparse.  Will working with the VectorMatrixMN still be efficient if it is not sparse anymore?

Comment: The `RepeatedElementVector` is actually even more efficient than the generic sparse vector in terms of memory usage (it stores just one double value, and one length field). So yes, it should be possible to keep all the efficiency benefits. You will need to be a bit careful about subsequent operations of course (you don't want to convert the whole thing back into a dense matrix, for example).

Comment: Thanks, all I need to do with it after normalizing is multiply it by a dense (but smaller) matrix.  

Should I grab the 0.13.0 release to play with, or the development branch?

Comment: oh, one more question, do I need to instantiate a new RepeatedElementVector for each row where I need it, or can I do it once, and use the same Vector in multiple rows?

Comment: You can re-use `RepeatedElementVector`s just fine. 0.26.0 is the latest version, should be available on Maven Central. Your specific case may need a slightly customised matrix multiply to get optimal performance - if you find it too slow then please file an issue and I'll fix it up in 0.27.0

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  When I'm creating my sparse matrix at first, it's a symmetric matrix, so I'm setting element (a,b) and (b,a) at the same time.  Does your suggestion to use a `SparseIndexedVector` for each row still apply?  I guess I'd have to initialize them all when I first initialize the matrix, and then fill in values in the relevant vectors as I go along?

Comment: SparseIndexedVector should still work fine (though you'll need to duplicate the symmetric elements). The fiddly bit might be constructing them, as you currently need to pre-specify the non-zero values. You may need to accumulate the non-zero indexes in ArrayLists, and then build the SparseIndexedVector in one shot. If I can think of a better way I'll let you know....

Comment: It's not immediately apparent from the javadocs what the right way to create/initialize a `SpareIndexedVector` is.

Comment: The various `SparseIndexedVector.create(...)` methods should do the trick?

Comment: So, might the best approach be to clone a `ZeroMatrix` to an `AMatrix`, fill in the non-zero values, then use `SparseIndexedVector.createFromRow` to create the sparse vectors and combine them into a VectorMatrix?

Comment: Yes a big Matrix should work, assuming you can fit the big dense matrix in memory. If not, you'll need something cleverer (e.g. the ArrayList trick). `0.27.0` will have a few enhancements that help with this, including incremental building of sparse matrices.

Comment: Thanks.  Which instantiation of AMatrix would be best to use for the "other" matrix.  I have the big 32K x 32K VectorMatrix and I need a second matrix that is 32K x 10 (approximately, but anyhow a small number).  I set it up by row, so maybe another VectorMatrix makes sense, but would that be optimal for being multiplied by?

Comment: Also, I can't see how to do a basic matrix multiplication.  I need to do m2 = m1 x m2 where m1 is my large normalized matrix, and m2 is my second matrix (n rows, only a few columns)

Comment: The `innerProduct` function should be your best bet - it's equivalent to matrix multiply for 2D matrices. m2 is probably best implemented as a `Matrix` (generic dense matrix). I think you'll need the upcoming `0.27.0` to make this work efficiently, it contains important optimisations for sparse matrices.

Comment: Let me know when 0.27.0 is available.  I was wondering if innerProduct would work -- I'm only familiar with it as a function between vectors.

Comment: I created a quick sparse matrix demo which roughly mirrors your use case: https://github.com/mikera/vectorz/blob/develop/src/test/java/example/SparseMatrix.java

Comment: `0.27.0` is now released, should be appearing on Maven Central shortly.

Comment: Thanks.  Is `SparseRowMatrix` new in 0.27.0?  Should it maybe be called `SparseVectorMatrix` instead since a `RowMatrix` is a single row?

Comment: It's to distinguish it from `SparseColumnMatrix` which is equally sparse but stores the sparse data in columns. I couldn't think of a better name that disambiguates them.....

Comment: `SparseRowVectorMatrix` and `SparseColumnVectorMatrix`?  It seems like they are fundamentally VectorMatrices, so that should figure in the name.  Not a big deal, but a touch confusing, since `RowMatrix` and `ColumnMatrix` mean something else.

Comment: or `SparseRowStorageMatrix` and `SparseColumnStorageMatrix` if they are not subclasses of `VectorMatrix`

Comment: does Vectorz have any built-in support for symmetric matrices?  I am finding that creating my initial T matrix is also very slow.  Because of the symmetry, I am doing `t.set(i,j,val)` and `t.set(j,i,val)` where t is right now implemented as a `VectorMatrixMN` (but should probably be a `SparseRowMatrix` in 0.27.0, but I haven't upgraded to that yet) but obviously setting "random" values like that is not efficient.  I am doing all the `j`'s that have values for a given `i` at once, so could be building up the matrix by building a Vector for the row, so...

Comment: ...so, I am wondering if there's some way to just set the (i,j) values first, and then do some efficient operation to copy the upper right triangle to the lower left to "symmetrify" the matrix?  Your thoughts?  Thanks again for all your help and support here!

Comment: **correction** my initial t matrix where I'm setting the values, I didn't set up as a sparse matrix, but I think I should.  Right now I'm just creating a regular zero matrix: `AMatrix t = ZeroMatrix.create(n, n).clone();`

Comment: Theoretically a sparse symmetric matrix wrapper would be possible, that only stores the upper triangle and reflects on index lookup wehnever i>j. Could be a new Vectorz wrapper class. I'm not sure it would perform wel though: I think a SparseRowMatrix containing SparseHashedVectors for each row is probably your best bet.

Comment: ZeroMatrix.clone() will create a big dense array at present.... probably not what you want. I think a SparseRowMatrix with a SparseHashedVector in each row is probably best: something like the example code that I posted

Comment: BTW no problem, happy to help! It's actually pretty useful for me to see different use cases in order to refine the API and implementation

Comment: Is there better place to discuss this?  I have another question about VectorBuilder that probably doesn't really belong here.

Comment: btw, I have switched over to using a SparseRowMatrix with a SparseIndexedVector for each row.  I am just creating the rows using the top triangle data, and then going through and copying to the bottom triangle at the end, and that's performing fairly well.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44809/discussion-between-purplevermont-and-mikera)

Comment: even using the new SparseRowMatrix, using setRow is extremely slow.  For my 32K x 32K matrix, about 10K of the rows are zeros so they branch to the setRow.  Doing that takes about 5.5 hours on my development machine.  If I replace the setRow with setting a boolean in a boolean array, the whole normalization takes under a minute.  The row.divide that happens for 2/3 of the rows is super fast. I tried row.add(uniformWeight) there, but that is also very slow (probably especially because those rows are represented by SparseIndexedVectors so new non-zero values are appearing in each spot)

Comment: to clarify, when dealing with a zero row, I tried to replace the very slow m.setRow(i, uniformRowVector) with m.getRow(i).add(uniformWeight) figuring that adding uniformWeight to each zero would be the same as just replacing the row with a row of all uniformWeight, but that is obviously also not fast, particularly since the row was implemented as a SparseIndexedVector which was great when it was all zeros, and awful when trying to add a constant value to each zero.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the la4j library. I do see several places of improvement in your code. Here is my advice:

Calling `getRow` (as well as `setRow`) is always a bad idea (especially for sparse matrices), since it launches a full-copying of the matrix row. I would suggest you to avoid such calls. Thus, w/o `getRow`/`setRow` code should looks like:

```
SparseMatrix t = new CRSMatrix(n, n);

double uniformWeight = (double) 1 / n; // used when the rowSum is zero
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  double rowSum = t.foldRow(i, Matrices.asSumAccumulator(0.0));
  if (rowSum > 0.0) {
    MatrixFunction divider = Matrices.asDivFunction(rowSum);
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      // TODO: I should probably think about `updateRow` method
      //       in order to avoid this loop
      t.update(i, j, divider);
    }
  } else {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
      t.set(i, j, uniformWeight);
    }
  }
}
```

Please, try this. I didn't compile it, but it should work.

**Update**

Using a boolean array in order to keep track of the same rows is a fantastic idea. The main bottle-neck here is the loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
  t.set(i, j, uniformWeight);
}
```

Here we're completely ruining the performance/footprint of the sparse matrice since assigning the entire row to the same value. So, I would say, combining these two ideas together: avoid `getRow/setRow` + extra array with flags (I would use BitSet instead, it is much efficien in terms of footprint) should give you an awesome performance.

Thank you for using the la4j library, and please, report any issues with performance/functional to mail-list, or GitHub page. All references are available here: http://la4j.org.

Comment: thanks for your reply and your help!  I won't have a chance to play with this until next week, but I appreciate your suggestions to update the individual cells one-by-one rather than using `setRow` and also the `foldRow` approach to doing the row sum.

I did implement my option #3 above (keep track of the uniform rows instead of actually modifying them, and then hack the matrix multiplication accordingly) which did save a ton of time.  I'm edit my Q above so I can show you that code and you can make any suggestions to improve it. (I'll accept your reply once I try it.)

Comment: I did finally get around to playing with this, and the foldRow and setting items one-by-one do help, as well as the trick of tracking the zero rows separately rather than actually normalizing them in place.  I'm benchmarking against Vectorz now, using my specific data use case.